# Remove index.php from laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5

How to remove index.php from http://localhost/lvoffc/index.php/login where "lvoofc" is the name of my project.

- http://localhost/lvoffc/index.php/login---> Working
- http://localhost/lvoffc/login--->  Shows "The requested URL
  /lvoffc/login was not found on this server."
- http://localhost/lvoffc/index.php/register--> Working
- http://localhost/lvoffc/register--> Shows "The requested URL
  /lvoffc/login was not found on this server."

I have tried the following:

1. move the index.php and .htaccess from a public to root directory
2. rename the server.php to index.php and move the .htaccess file to the root directory.
   but i'm not successful in removing index.php from the URL

Comment: enable rewrite module in apache

Comment: a2enmod rewrite running this command on terminal give me
Module rewrite already enabled 
But still not working

Comment: @Vik, post your `.htaccess`

Comment: <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: http://localhost:8000/login Works but not http://localhost/lvoffc/login